# Using dapper async within a transaction

Tags: asynchronous, transactions, dapper

We are currently using dapper to handle some very expensive update / delete scenarios and we are very pleased with it.

Now we have the following scenario which I want to speed up.

- Update 1 takes about ~60 seconds.
- Update 2 takes <1 second.

If we do this the sync way, we'll spend around 61 seconds waiting in total.
Can we speed this up, to call the first update with the `ExecuteAsync` method, but not await it. Like so:

```
Connection.ExecuteAsync("Update 1", new { someValue }, Transaction, 120);
Connection.Execute("Update 2", new { someValue }, Transaction);
```

Notice the lack of `await` keyword.

This will speed things up, but is it a good idea, and will it work in a transaction?
What happens when the transaction commit is hit, and the first update is still executing? 
Or is it a bad idea to use ExecuteAsync without await ?

*Assuming update 2 is not dependent on update 1.*

Answer (score 0):

If the first update doesn't work in the same data of the second and you don't need to wait the result, you can execute it in async mode without await.
I suggest you to read this page:

http://www.joesauve.com/async-dapper-and-async-sql-connection-management/

It explain how to execute async commands with an async connection to the database, I think it can be useful for you.